# How to create different scroll bars for each container

Tags: html, css, angular5

I have several containers on one page and I want them look different in each container.
I'm developing in Angular5 and I've tried by defining

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {  
   /*contents are different in each css file.*/
   ...
}
```

into every css file.(Each container is included in its own component and uses its own css file.)
But they still look the same.
How can I fix it. 
It is really easy but I'm not good at css so please help me.

Comment: Hi. I'm Marat.
So you mean that you defined difference css code for scrollbar into different css file?

Comment: Yes, Of course. I've 2 containers of sidebar and contents in one page and I want them to have different scrollbars.

Comment: You can fix it by inserting the scrollbar styles in different classes. I'll answer the question soon.

Comment: Very good. It works now.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want my help after now, please contact me anytime.
I'm always ready to answer any questions related with web development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html:

```html
<div class="container sidebar">
 ...
</div>
<div class="container contents">
 ...
</div>
```

css:

```css
.sidebar ::-webkit-scrollbar {
 ...
}
.contents ::-webkit-scrollbar {
 ...
}
```